# Hyperlink nos comentários

Tags: suporte, formatação, comentários

Nos comentários que eu fiz até hoje não consegui colocar hyperlinks, sempre coloco os links soltos no comentário.

Como eu faço para colocar hyperlink ?? Precisa de alguma permissão específica ?

Comment: O link que fica a direita do campo de comentário, escrito **ajuda**, ilustra como fazer também, assim como outras formatações de texto (negrito, itálico, etc)

Answer (score 14):

A sintaxe é assim:

> `[o texto a mostrar](http://o.link.a.mostrar)`

O resultado é:

[o texto a mostrar](http://o.link.a.mostrar)

Ou seja: Colchetes à volta do texto, e parenteses à volta do url/link, sem espaços entre as duas partes.

Comment: E funciona assim tanto nos comentários como nos posts: [o texto a mostrar](http://o.link.a.mostrar)

Comment: Não sei se tem alguma referência aqui no sopt mas o nome é [mini-Markdown](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/216929/185667), explicado à direita quando se faz un comentário no link "Ajuda"